# How Can One Use a Count Down For-Loop to Count Up Squares?

Tags: java, for-loop

To paraphrase my question, I want to use a for-loop that counts down but prints numbers by increasing order. In my case, I want a for-loop that prints squares. Here is my current code:

```
//countdown to countup. Output should be : 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81

for(int x = 10; x > 0; x--)
{
    System.out.print((int)Math.pow(10,2)); // maths goes here

}
```

This code segment is almost done, I just want to know what the math is. It's either I'm over thinking it or I'm outright missing something.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a loop that counts up?

Comment: `Math.pow(10-x, 2)`, maybe?

Comment: Student programmer, question requires a countdown loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first argument that you pass to the `pow()` method should be (10-x), not 10.

```
for(int x = 10; x > 0; x--)
{
    System.out.print((int)Math.pow((10-x),2)); // maths goes here

}
```